# Dinner party permutations

Tags: combinatorics

I was at dinner and we started discussing this problem:

4 people sitting in chairs at dinner, and various people leave to go to the bathroom.

How many total unique permutations are there of people sitting at the table if a unique permutation also depends on which chair you are sitting in (so a unique permutation depends on who is there, and which chair they are sitting in)

I'm not sure whether it would just be 2^4 (the number of combinations of people, including/excluding each of them) times 4! (the rotations in chairs) but then we were trying to figure out if this is over counting or under counting.

Answer (score 2):

The formula is given by :
\begin{gather}
\sum_{i=1}^4 {{4}\choose{i}}^2 i! = 208
\end{gather}

**Explanation:** For every possible number i of people around the table, there is   ${{4}\choose{i}}$ ways to choose which people are around the table, ${{4}\choose{i}}$ to choose the used chairs and $i!$ ways to permute the people with the chairs.

Comment: Nice answer.  However, the boldface word should be Explanation.